# Populate an ul from a JSON database by HTTP request

Tags: javascript, json, localhost, httprequest

I am stuck on this problem. I have an JSON DB and I want to request data from it by HTTP. After that, I want to make li's in an ul with the data I got as answer. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>X</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function requestBrands()
    {
        adress="http://localhost:3000/brands?callback=?"
        $.getJSON(adress ,function(answer)
        {
            var ul = document.getElementById("x");
            $.each(answer, function(index, brands)
            {               
                ???????
            }
            )
        }
        )
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<button onclick="solicitareMarca()">Brands categ</button>
</div>

<div >
    <h3">Brands</h3>
    <ul id="x">
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSON DB:

```
{
  "brands":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Audi"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"BMW"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't find how to inject the data in the ul.

Comment: In your code, `answer` is the entire Object, with a `brands` property. It's an object, so you cannot do `$.each(answer...`. You can do `answer.brands.forEach((brand, i) => { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the below code

```
 $.each(answer.brands, function(index, brand)
 {               
    $("#x").append(`<li> Id:${brand.id} Car name: ${brand.name} </li>`);
 }
```

But as your answer contains brands as an array so please pass answer.brands as argument to `$.each(answer.brands)` function instead of `$.each(answer)`.